# Inject TimeZone To Convert From UTC

Tags: c#

My first time working with DateTime in C#. We print out delivery tickets and because our system runs on UTC, I need to convert the date on the ticket back to local time so that tickets with an Estimated Arrival after 6:00PM dont show up as the next day.

I've gotten the timezone from the well and now I am struggling with how to inject the new timezone into my new view model for the ticket.

The error I get is:

[image]

After reading, I understand that my truck.EstimatedArrival may be nullable so i tried to insert an .HasValue but so far I can't get the syntax to work for me. Any suggestions on how I need to lay this out?

```
public async Task<DispatchTruckTicketViewModel> GetDeliveryTruckTicket(string truckId)
    {
        var truck = await _dispatchTruckRepo.GetDispatchTruckForTicket(truckId);

        var dispatchId = await _dispatchRepo.GetAllQueryable()
        .Include(did => did.SourceWell.Id)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(did => truck.DispatchId == did.Id);
       

        var well = await _wellRepo.GetAllQueryable()
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(w => w.Id == dispatchId.SourceWellId);
   

        TimeZoneInfo tz;
        tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(well.TimeZoneName);

        if (truck.EstimatedArrival.HasValue){
            TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(truck.EstimatedArrival, tz);
        } -- still not working, same error as above.
        
        if (truck == null)
        {
            throw new ServiceException("Truck does not exist");
        }

        var model = new DispatchTruckTicketViewModel
        {
            Id = truck.Id,
            Type = "Delivery",
            TicketNumber = truck.TicketNumber,
            OrderedBy = await _accountService.GetNameFromUserId(truck.Dispatch.Header.CreateUserId),
            // DateShipped = truck.EstimatedArrival?.ToLocalTime().ToShortDateString() ?? "",
            DateShipped = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(truck.EstimatedArrival, tz).ToShortDateString() ?? "",
            Items = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DispatchItem>, IEnumerable<DispatchItemViewModel>>(truck.Items),
            DriverName = truck.DriverName,
            SwamperName = truck.SwamperName,
        };
        AddWellInformation(model, truck.Dispatch.DestinationWell);
        return model;
    }
```

Comment: Aside, If truck is null your code will fail long before it reaches the test for truck == null.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is:

```
        TimeZoneInfo tz;
        tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(well.TimeZoneName);

        if (truck.EstimatedArrival.HasValue){
            TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(truck.EstimatedArrival.Value, tz);
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle failure of getting estimated time
        }
```

`HasValue` of a nullable value type returns true when the element has a value (is not null). To get the value, you need to call its `Value` property. As a shortcut, you might use the `GetValueOrDefault()` method.